# Mocking functions in rust

Tags: unit-testing, rust

Is there a way to mock regular functions in rust?

Consider the following code:

```rust
fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo());
}

fn get_user_input() -> u8 {
    // Placeholder for some unknown value
    42
}

fn foo() -> u8 {
    get_user_input()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_foo() {
        use super::*;

        get_user_input = || 12u8;

        assert_eq!(foo(), 12u8);
    }
}
```

I would like to unit test `foo()` without having to rely on the output of `get_user_input()`.
I obviously cannot overwrite `get_user_input()` like I tried in the example code.

I have only found ways to mock structs, traits and modules but nothing about mocking regular free functions. Am I missing something?

Edit: I have looked primarily at the `mockall` crate.

Comment: The way you have written the code, `foo()` is unconditionally calling `get_user_input()`, and there is nothing you can do purely in the test to change that. You need to write your code in a way to allow injecting a different function. The easiest way is to define a trait, say `UserInput`, with an assoicated function `get()`, and make `foo()` generic over `T: UserInput`. You can then have a standard implementation for `UserInput` for the actual code, and another one just for the tests.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use cfg:

```rust
#[cfg(not(test))]
fn get_user_input() -> u8 {
    // Placeholder for some unknown value
    42
}

#[cfg(test)]
fn get_user_input() -> u8 {
    12
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ab2d03b383638f20f38416dfde7fa0e1)

Or dependency injection:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    println!("{}", foo(get_user_input));
}

fn get_user_input() -> u8 {
    // Placeholder for some unknown value
    42
}

fn foo(get_user_input_: impl Fn() -> u8) -> u8 {
    get_user_input_()
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    #[test]
    fn test_foo() {
        use super::*;
        
        let get_user_input = || 12u8;

        assert_eq!(foo(get_user_input), 12u8);
    }
}
```

[playgound](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=18f1349dc1bef45cd5c8b998dbcd1447)